# Converting a Dictionary to a List with formatting

Tags: c#, linq

I have zero experience working with Oracle and am using Oracle XE to test my code.

I have run into a small issue. Hope to get some help.

Well, I am trying to build a cross DB platform application where I need to generate SELECT statements dynamically. I have got the statement working for all but Oracle as oracle expects the column names to be in quotes, else I start getting "INVALID IDENTIFIER" errors.

For example the below statement doesnt work for me but if I put firstname in quotes, it works.

```
SELECT firstname
FROM
"emp"
```

However, this works

```
SELECT "firstname"
FROM
"emp"
```

Now coming back to the piece of code that I am working on.

```
var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder();

if (sourceType == DataSource.OracleServer)
{
    sourceBuilder.Append("SELECT ")
      .Append(String.Join(", ", (mappedColumnsList.Select(x => x.Key))))
      .Append(" FROM ").Append(sourceAttribute);

}
else
    sourceBuilder.Append("SELECT ")
      .Append(String.Join(", ", mappedColumnsList.Select(x => x.Key)))
      .Append(" FROM ").Append(sourceAttribute);
```

Now I need to add a double quote to the place where I am flattening my dictionary, when the sourceType is Oracle.

I tried using

```
sourceBuilder.Append("SELECT ")
  .Append(String.Join(", ", string.Format("\"" + mappedColumnsList.Select(x => x.Key) + "\"")))
  .Append(" FROM ").Append(sourceAttribute);
```

But obviously, this doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change this:

```
string.Format("\"" + mappedColumnsList.Select(x => x.Key) + "\"")
```

To:

```
mappedColumnsList.Select(x => "\"" + x.Key + "\"")
```